# How to use another Apple ID to submit an already-online iOS app to the App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, appstore-approval

My company had outsourced an iOS app to another company, and they published the app on the App Store using their Apple ID. The app have been available for download for a few months and has a number of users. Now my company developed a slightly newer version of the app and would like to distribute the app using our own Apple ID. What's the correct way to do it? The major concerns we have are:

1. Should we submit the newer version using our ID before or after we take the old app down from the App Store. Would it happen that the newer app get rejected because Apple feel the two apps are too similar? (Actually they are quite similar, for that the update is slim.)
2. Is there a graceful way to notify the currently online app's users that they should switch to the newer app? And How to coordinate it, since the newer app may take a certain amount of time to get approved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some different scenarios here, I am going to try to address some of them to see which one helps you the most:

1-)You have a current application that contains no use of push notification and no use of in app purchase. This is the easiest one. Basically, It does not matter what version the user has had before. You can remove the old one from the previous developer account and add it to the new developer account. By completely removing the previous application (not just from the app store listing, but from the developer account), you can reuse the bundle ID. When the user reinstall the app, the user will be able to replace the old application with the new application (note that the new application will not appear on the user's update list).

2-)You have push notification. Here, you will have to keep the old application if you wish to maintain the push notification certificates, so, the new application will have to use a new bundle ID, which means that the app will appear on the user as a new application, and the user will be able to have both app simultaneously.

3-)You have in app purchase and subscriptions. You will need to remove the old in app purchase entries from the old developer account, and add it to the new account (if you wish to reuse the product id, if not, you will have to create it either way).

I am not sure what kind of measure you need to take if you are using iCloud and/or other services. Best course of action is to contact Apple developer support. They will give you some guidance on what to do with your specific case. Also, when submitting, make sure to point to the reviewer that you are trying to move the application from one company to another. I think they can access review notes from the review to the previous submission(instead of reviewing it as a new app), and speed up the process.

Edit: You can not transfer apps between companies using iTunes connect. More information here: [link](https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=6112013c)

Comment: The app does use push notification. Regarding the push notification certificates, what's the cost to change it? Can I use the same bundle ID if I change the push notification certificates?

Comment: You will have to have new push notification certificate for the new app, regardless of using the same or different bundle ID. However, if you wish to send push notification to the users with the previous developer account submission, you will have to keep the old application active (therefore, changing the bundle ID of the new application) on the old developer account in order to have valid certificate and app information. Basically, you will need new bundle ID for your app.

Comment: If you maintain your device token identifier for the push notification, keep in mind that you will need to identify the push notification token for the new application with the new developer account. You won't be able to send push to applications with tokens from the old developer account.